# Secure NodeJs API routes

Tags: node.js, angular, express, security, one-time-password

I was working on login with OTP functionality in my app. The client side is in Angular and backend is built on ExpressJs. However, I couldn't figure out how I can secure this api. Whenever I try to hit the api using postman it just work fine and send the otp.
So the issue arise if anyone run a loop and hit the api with all type of header configuration it will just keep sending otp until credit ends.

Could anyone help in this please.

Answer (score 2):

It's just an idea.
How about implementing rate limit so that the client can make only so many calls in a given period of time. You can use libraries like [express-rate-limit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-rate-limit) but generally these are implemented on external service such as cloud load balancers, cloud firewalls, nginx,etc.
And you can also implement captcha and have some sort of API key or authentication
at your client side to make API calls to your OTP generation endpoint.

Hope this helps.